# Expressão regular PHP, como remover tags html aberto?

Tags: php, string, regex, html-tags

Olá! Preciso remover da minha string um trecho html que bugou, ele estra assim:

```
e="text-align:left;"> Texto normal ...
```

Isso gera um erro visual.
Outro erro que ta gerando é no final do texto ex:

```
<p style="text-ali ...
```

Aqui ficou faltando o resto da tag e fechamento, o que gera mais erros.

Tem alguma expressão regular para remover somente o (>) e (<) quando estiverem com erro de formatação, no caso uma tentativa falha de marcação html?

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com essa [resposta no Stack Overflow em Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482254/regex-that-strip-unclosed), você pode fazer assim:

```
$html = preg_replace("/<([^<>]*)(?=<|$)/", "$1", $html); # remove '<' os não fechados
$html = preg_replace("/(^|(?<=>))([^<>]*)>/", "$1", $html); # remove os '>' não fechados
```

Ainda de acordo com a segunda resposta do link acima, temos uma explicação seguinte:

Tradução meia-boca minha:

> Para um `<` não fechado, é possível substituir `<(?=[^>]*(<|$))` por uma string vazia. Ele corresponde todos `<` que não são seguidas por um fechamento de `>` antes da próxima `<`, ou no fim da linha.
>
> Para a `>` não aberta, você pode substituir `((^|>)[^<]*)>` por `$1`.
>   Ele coincide com o texto que começa com um `>` (ou o início de linha), não contém `<` e termina com a `>`. `$1`  representa tudo, exceto o último `>`.